# Market value of futures

Tags: futures, valuation, financial-markets, calculation

What is the market value of an (index) futures?

I guess the market value is either:

1. `quantity * contract size * price`
2. zero, if the daily unrealized PnL is disregarded

The contract is entered at zero cost, so should the market value also be considered zero? I can see arguments for both alternatives. Is there a common consensus for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it is marked to market at some frequency (so that the unrealized P/L is realized by both parties who have entered the contract) then after each marking the value will be zero, and in between markings the value will be whatever the unrealized P/L is.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Thanks!